# xpath 1.0 : subset matches an attribute list?

Tags: xpath

In xml I have elements with an attribute that contains a list of categories for example : cat="A B C D"

Is there any possibility with xpath 1.0 (I'm using xslt in Firefox) to return all the elements where a subset of categories matches the list?

For example :

subset(A C) cat(A B C) true

subset(D) cat(A C) false

subset(A C) cat(A B) false

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that should do basically what you want. The XSLT wrapper is just to set the variables.

```
<xsl:variable name="subset" select="A C" />
<xsl:variable name="matches"
    select="//*[translate($subset, concat(@cat, ' '), '') = '']" />
```

Of course, you may need to tweak `//*` depending on what kinds of elements you're trying to match.

Concatenating a space to `@cat` is only necessary if you may have subset strings like `'D'` that contain no spaces.

This code also assumes that all category names are single letters. If that's not the case, let me know.

Comment: Alternately, you could use Saxon CE in Firefox, which provides XSLT 2.0 (including XPath 2.0). Then you'd have tokenize() at your disposal, which would help if the category names are not single letters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the code.

In fact, my categories contain normally more than one letter and it is possible that there are subcategories (for example : AB.CD where the point is the delimiter for the subcategory). It would be nice if I can also search only one part of a category (for example :

subset(A Z.Y) cat(A.B Z.Y) true